# How to convert SQL Server timestamp object to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, timestamp

I need your help with a small problem, I have a column (data type `timestamp`) in SQL Server 2008.

Now I want to show this `timestamp` value as a string in an ASP.Net C# app. Is there any way to do that?

I tried it using regular data fetching in ASP.Net but it produced System.byte[] as output rather than actual value. In SQL Server Management Studio values are represented as `0x000000000000B3C0`.

Comment: Just an FYI, timestamp is a automatically generated binary number, which is guaranteed to be unique within a database. timestamp is typically used to version rows entered into a table and not to display date and/or time.

Comment: Right, timestamp shouldn't be used instead of "DateCreated" for example.

Comment: Just search the site "convert byte[] to string" and you will get plenty of results

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change it to the Date, while getting from the database. Like:

```
SELECT timestamp = DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', yourTimestampColumn) 
    FROM yourTable
```

Comment: I would also like to add that the timestamp datatype has nothing to do with date and time values. It is a binary number that increments upon changes made to the database. So, probably, my answer may not help you. You need to check your implementation of timestamp field.

Comment: I actually I have to compare that timestamp with previous value of the same row before updating or deleting data. Is there any way to compare.

Comment: You can add a new DateTime column, which has a default value of GetDate() function is Sql Server. So, it will keep on adding the current DateTime value whenever a new record is inserted. Now before updating, compare this value with the current value of GetDate() function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i catch you, but in sql you can cast timestamp value to datetime then to varchar like this:

```
declare @val timestamp = 0x0000AAE200B29565
 select cast(cast(@val as datetime) as varchar(max))
```